# how to get value from textbox using typescript in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a beginner to angular2 / typescript I'm trying get numbers from two textboxes and adding both numbers and display the result using interpolation

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: 
`<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<h1>{{D}}</h1>
 <form>
  <p>first number:<input type="text" id="num1"></p>
  <p>second number:<input type ="text1" id="num2"></p>
  <h1> {{result}}</h1>
  </form>
   <test-app></test-app>`
  })

  export class AppComponent 
  { 
 name = 'Angular'; 
 value : number;value1 : number;result:number;
  constructor(value : number,value1 : number,result:number)
  {

  this.value = parseFloat
  ((document.getElementById("text") as HTMLInputElement).value);
  this.value1 = parseFloat((document.getElementById("text1") 
  as HTMLInputElement).value);
  this.result=this.value+this.value1;
  }}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html

Comment: Binding to form elements is something that is covered in the very beginning of almost any angular tutorial including the many how-to's and tutorial on the main angular 2 site. Follow the link @echonax posted and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: have you ever read something in angular?

Comment: I have readed @Aravind

Comment: after reading you didnt get these information?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way is to use template reference variable:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-little-tour',
  template: `
    <input #newHero > 
    <button (click)="addHero(newHero.value)">Add</button>
})

export class LittleTourComponent {
  addHero(newHero: string) {
    console.log(newHero)
  }
}
```

A complete guide for User Input in Angular can be found here:  https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: I got a problem when the input id is dynmic like `#newHero{{i}}`, I pass  its value to the click method like this `(click)="addHero(newHero{{i}}.vaue"`  but it cause compile error, I have no idea how to do it right , any help with a push in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

if you get without using ngModel:

```
var   num1= ((document.getElementById("num1") as HTMLInputElement).value);
var   num2= ((document.getElementById("num2") as HTMLInputElement).value);
var result=parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 9):

HTML

```
<p>first number:<input type="text" id="num1" [(ngModel)] = "value" ></p>
<p>second number:<input type ="text1" id="num2" [(ngModel)] = "value1"></p>
<h1> {{value + value1}}</h1>
```

Component class

```
 export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Thank you , for the answer but with using a button event how can we do that

Comment: Add a button in your html <button (click) = "addValues()">Add</button> . In class make addValues function. 
addValues() {
  this.result = this.value + this.value1;
}
replace value + value1 by result in h1 tag.

Comment: Also declare value, value1 and result variables in component class.

Answer (score 6):

HTML

```
<p>first number:<input type="number" [(ngModel)]='a'></p>
<p>second number:<input type ="number" [(ngModel)]='b'></p>
<h1>{{a + b}}</h1>
```

Component

```
export class AppComponent 
  { 
 a: number = 0; //set default value as 0
 b: number = 0;

}
```

Comment: problem will be that if    a = 4  and b = 5    you want the total to sum , thus in h1 it should show 9 ,  but actually that is going to show  45

Answer (score 3):

```
app.component.html

<div>
      <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='userName' placeholder='user name' class='user_id_text'>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type='password' [(ngModel)]='password' placeholder='password' class='user_id_password'>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type='submit' value='Login' (click)='registeredUser($event)'>
      </div>

app.component.ts

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
userName ='';
password = '';

ngOnInit(){
  console.log(this.userName+' password -'+this.password);
}
registeredUser(){
 let {userName,password} = this;

 if(userName=='ssss' && password == 'ssss'){
    console.log(userName+' password -'+password);
 }
}
```

}
Explanation - ngModel with [()] is two-way binding. the value in the UI always syncs back to the domain model in your class

Comment: Very helpful that you show the complete solution. Only in my case it didn't like the ` symbol -- had to replace with ". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
      <p>first number:<input type="text" ngModel name="num1" id="num1"></p>
    <p>second number:<input type="text" ngModel name="num2" id="num2"></p>
</form>
<test-app></test-app>`
  })

export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor() {
  }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
      console.log(f.form.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> html :

```
 <input type="text" id="obj_id" >
```

> ts > read as :

```
 (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(obj_id)).value
```

> If object is involved such as in for loop,text boxes are to be given
>   ids from object field values then Use **[id]** instead of **id**

```
<input type="text" [id]="obj.field"  >
```