# Angular on keyup.enter send the current text of an input to a method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input which I want to get the text that it's currently got and send it to a method.

Here is the code:

app.component.html

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="sendit()" />
```

app.component.ts

```
sendit() {
    console.log(The text in the input);
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply you can do like following,

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="sendit($event.target.value)" />

 sendit(data){
    console.log("Value",data)
 }
```

[image]

Using Two way binding here is an solution,

[how to get value from textbox using typescript in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410011/how-to-get-value-from-textbox-using-typescript-in-angular-2)

I hope it's helps to you.

Thanks,

Muthu

Answer (score 16):

There are multiple ways you can do this:

#### Use a template variable for the `input`. You'll get the `value` of it like this:

```
<input #yourInput type="text" (keyup.enter)="sendit(yourInput.value)" />
```

And in Component, get it like this:

```
sendit(inputValue) {
  console.log(inputValue);
}
```

#### Alternatively, you can also use `[(ngModel)]` to bind the text field two ways:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="bindedTwoWays"
  (keyup.enter)="sendit(bindedTwoWays)" >
```

And in Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  bindedTwoWays = 'Angular';

  sendit(inputValue) {
    console.log(inputValue);
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljiak4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with both the approaches for your ref.

Answer (score 2):

Create a template variable for the `input` element and pass your input value like this

```
<input #inp type="text" (keyup.enter)="sendit(inp.value)" />
       ^^^^                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

Accept via

```
sendit(inputValue) {
    console.log(inputValue);
}
```